# C++ Initialising std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractClass>>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I've derived `std::vector` and I'm trying to initialise it.  I don't understand why the following is happening:

```
namespace Bpm {
typedef std::unique_ptr<PolingNormalised> PolingNormalisedPtr;
class PolingNormalisedArray : public std::vector<std::unique_ptr<PolingNormalised>>
{
    using std::vector<std::unique_ptr<PolingNormalised>>::vector;
};
}

// Works perfectly
Bpm::PolingNormalisedArray qpmNormArray;
qpmNormArray.push_back(std::move(Bpm::PolingNormalisedPtr(new Bpm::QpmNormalised(2.))));

// Doesn't compile
Bpm::PolingNormalisedArray qpmNormArray(std::move(Bpm::PolingNormalisedPtr(new Bpm::QpmNormalised(2.))));

// Doesn't compile
Bpm::PolingNormalisedArray qpmNormArray(Bpm::PolingNormalisedPtr(new Bpm::QpmNormalised(2.));

// Doesn't compile
Bpm::PolingNormalisedArray qpmNormArray(new Bpm::QpmNormalised(2.));
```

I don't understand why many of the initialisation methods do not compile.  What's going on here?  What's the proper way to initialise the `std::vector`?

Thank you.

Comment: `// Doesn't compile` `// Doesn't compile` `// Doesn't compile` How about you post those errors? And a nice [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go with them?

Comment: Why should it work? `std::vector` has no matching constructors for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you get rid of all the `unique_ptr`s and aliases running around in your example, what you're trying to do in the cases that don't compile boils down to this:

```
#include <vector>

struct foo{};

int main()
{
    std::vector<foo> vec(foo{});
}
```

This obviously won't compile because [`std::vector` has no constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) that takes an instance of the `value_type` as its argument.

Either use `vector::push_back` as you've shown in your example, or use `vector::emplace_back` to construct the `unique_ptr` in-place within the `vector` without having to move it.

```
qpmNormArray.emplace_back(new Bpm::QpmNormalised(2.));
```